# OpenCV with Python - Rough edges on masked png image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I am trying to place this png image over the eyes in a webcam feed -
http://i.imgur.com/qdHHOpF.png

But while placing the image on the eyes, the edges are aliased and white. 
http://i.imgur.com/Nhw0Q20.png

Here is the code segment where the masks are created -

```
# Create the mask for the glasses
imgGlassesGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgGlasses, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imgGlassesGray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Create the inverted mask for the glasses
orig_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(orig_mask)
```

And here is the joining part -

```
            roi = roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2]            

            roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask)

            roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(glasses,glasses,mask = mask_inv)

            dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)

            roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2] = dst
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - Here is the part where the resizing is done -

```
            glasses = cv2.resize(imgGlasses, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask_inv = cv2.resize(orig_mask_inv, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Comment: No expert in OpenCV, but I suspect that the original image and the mask are different sizes. If you scale the normal and inverted image after the inversion, you could end up with two different images (apart from being inverted). Now, if you only want to paint the glasses black, a bitwise_or with the original glasses should do it. No inversion necessary... or conversion to grey for that  matter. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Sorry about that... I was way off. Well, not that far. To paint the glasses black on the original image, you have to do an and with the background image. White AND pixel will give you the pixel. Black AND pixel will set the pixel to the black. Use the original BGR values.

Comment: I've have added the re-sizing  part.  roi_fg gives the glasses alone, and roi_bg contains the background.

Comment: Did you try: 1) Resize glasses, 2) `Threshold` glasses (at 128) to avoid greys (`and` function does not work with greys), 3) `And` the original image with the mask. Don't convert the glasses mask - leave it in color (even though it's b/w). Only those three steps... I'd try it, but I don't have opencv installed at the moment.